# Angularjs Show and Hide Button within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list which populates a screen using `ng-repeat`.
Each row has a button for the user to click on to select the row. 
Typically what you would use a radio button for but the user wants a button toggle.

What I really want is to show the first button (hide the second on displaying the list first time) and after the user clicks on the first one to select a specific row, I want to hide the first button and show the second.
The 2 button have different ids, text, style.
So to the user, its like changing the look of the button after selection.

I tried setting the `showfarebut1` / `showfarebut2` scope variable in my function `populateFareOption(row.col3.value, row.col4.value)` in the controller, but all the rows had the second button after button one is clicked.

Any ideas or code snippet .. will be appreciated.

### HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rowList">
    <td> {{row.col1.value}}</td>

    <td>
        <span class="price">PRICE:&nbsp;
            <strong class="amount">{{row.col2.value}}</strong>
        </span>

        <button id="btnXX1" ng-show="showfarebut1" type="button" class="btn pull-right" ng-click="populateFareOption(row.col3.value,row.col4.value)">

            <span class="text pull-left" name="fareOption" ng-model="travelCardForm.colOption" value="{{row.col3.value}}">Select</span>
            <i class="icon-placeholder"></i>
        </button> 

        <button id="btnXX2" ng-show="showfarebut2" type="button" class="btn pull-right">
            <span class="text pull-left">Selected</span>
            <i class="selected-icon pull-right"></i>
        </button>
    </td> 
</tr>
```

### Controller

```
    $scope.showfarebut1=true;
    $scope.showfarebut2=false;

    $scope.populateFareOption = function(x,y){
         cardForm.fareOption.value=x;
         cardForm.productCode.value=y;
         $scope.showfarebut1=false;
         $scope.showfarebut2=true;
       }
```

Comment: You shouldn't have two elements with the same ID - that's what classes are for.

Comment: Can you share your controller where `showfarebut1` and `showfarebut2` are created?  If you want granularity, you probably need to add a couple of `visible` properties to the `row` you are iterating.

Comment: Thanks jraede and Davin ... I have update the snippet. The buttons now have different IDS.

Comment: @olatom You should not use static `id` attribute for elements inside `ng-repeat`. Consider using dynamic `id`s like `id="btn{{$index}}"` or don't use them at all. Otherwise you will have buttons with `id="btnXX1"` and `id="btnXX2"` in each row and therefore duplicate IDs, which produces wrong HTML and makes abuse of `id` attribute usage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example you have `showfarebut1` and `showfarebut2` shared across all the rows, that causes one button clicked affect all rows. You should use something bound to the current row: `row.showfarebut1` and `row.showfarebut2`.

However, there is a more efficient way to make toggle buttons. You can reuse the same button and set classes and text according to the state of the record. Here is a simple example:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="list-group" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="row in rowList">
    <span>{{row.col1.value}}</span>
    <span>{{row.col2.value}}</span>
    <button type="button" ng-click="row.selected=!row.selected" class="pull-right btn btn-xs">
      <span ng-class="{'glyphicon':true, 'glyphicon-ok':row.selected, 'glyphicon-plus':!row.selected}"></span>
      {{row.selected?'Selected':''}}
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can use [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive to toggle classes and condition like `{{row.selected?'Selected':''}}` to toggle text of the button.

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app', []).
  controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.rowList = [{
      col1: { value: 'r1c1'},
      col2: {value: 'r1c2'}
    }, {
      col1: {value: 'r2c1'},
      col2: {value: 'r2c2'}
    }, {
      col1: {value: 'r3c1'},
      col2: {value: 'r3c2'}
    }];
  });
```

You even don't need some special function for selecting an item, you can do simple things directly in [`ng-click`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/ZFRIWOe2HxMq8K11FBk4?p=preview

---

***Edit (adapted version):***

**HTML**

```
<table ng-controller="ctrl" class="table">
  <tr ng-repeat="row in rowList">
    <td>{{row.col1.value}}</td>
    <td>
      <span class="price">PRICE:&nbsp;
        <strong class="amount">{{row.col2.value}}</strong>
      </span>
      <button id="btn{{$index}}"  type="button" class="btn pull-right" ng-click="select(row)">
        <span class="text pull-left" name="fareOption" value="{{row.col3.value}}">{{row.selected?'Selected':'Select'}}</span>
        <i ng-class="{'icon-placeholder':!row.selected, 'selected-icon':row.selected, 'pull-right':row.selected}"></i>
      </button>
    </td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app', []).
  controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.rowList = [{
      col1: {value: 'Orange'},
      col2: {value: '10'},
      col3: {value: 'x1'},
      col4: {value: 'y1'}
    }, {
      col1: {value: 'Apple'},
      col2: {value: '20'},
      col3: {value: 'x2'},
      col4: {value: 'y2'}
    }, {
      col1: {value: 'Banana'},
      col2: {value: '15'},
      col3: {value: 'x3'},
      col4: {value: 'y3'}
    }];

    $scope.select = function(row) {
      row.selected=!row.selected;
      // Do something with row.col3.value and row.col4.value
    }
  });
```

**Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/DdO1zBXxkyXWSLA6Gv2x?p=preview

Comment: Vadim, I love your code and thanks for the time and expertise . But, I am using ready made style from the web design team and I have to code to the style. If only I can adapt your code to work as expected.

Comment: I am also trying the other answer below. Interested in both methods as they will be useful now and or in future development. am I missing something in yours.

Comment: @olatom I've added an adapted version that uses your markup and concepts from original answer.

Comment: Vadim! You have saved me days of banging my head on the wall. I was able to adopt use code in a few minutes and it semi-works, but I want the ability to be able to select only one button from the list i.e. like a radio button. Please, how would you do this. At the mo you can select multiple. I hope we won't have to discard the code, because its too good to be discarded!

Answer (score 0):

Attach `showfarebut2` to the object in `rowList`:

```
$scope.populateFareOption = function(row){
  cardForm.fareOption.value = row.col3.value;
  cardForm.productCode.value = row.col4.value;
  row.showFareBut2 = true;
}
```

And your HTML:

```
<button id="btnXX2" ng-show="row.showfarebut2" type="button" class="btn pull-right">
```

Comment: I have tried your logic but can get it to work.  The ng-show for each row should have an expression that evaluates to a true or false. When , the page is first loaded a want the first button displayed hence a true ng-show value for the first and second should be false by default. My problem is when the button is clicked your "row.showFareBut2 = true" above is not a scope object and how will it populate the ng-show for the second button. Besides, how do I change the ng-show for first. I must be missing something.